# When and when not to use activation function between input layer and hidden layer?

Tags: neural-networks, intuition

I am beginner to Neural Network and this question might be very basic and stupid. Expecting some intuitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

Activation function is always used between layers.

> Activation functions are really important for a Artificial Neural Network to learn and make sense of something really complicated and Non-linear complex functional mappings between the inputs and response variable.They introduce non-linear properties to our Network.Their main purpose is to convert a input signal of a node in a A-NN to an output signal. That output signal now is used as a input in the next layer in the stack.

Reference: https://towardsdatascience.com/activation-functions-and-its-types-which-is-better-a9a5310cc8f